# Magento 2 : Undefined Variable Issue

Tags: magento2, product, image

I am unable to get product id with this code, and getting error **imageUrl** **undefined**. Please let me know if any solution regarding this.

```
<?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
       <?php echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?> 
       <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid" > 
       <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
       <span style="width:270px;" class="product-image-container">
       <span style="padding-bottom: 137%;" class="product-image-wrapper"> 
       <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getId());
       $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); $imgCNT = 1; 
       foreach($images as $child){ if($imgCNT==1) {$imgurl1=$child->getUrl();}
       elseif($imgCNT==2) {$imgurl2=$child->getUrl();
       }
       else{
           break;
       }
       $imgCNT++;
       }
       $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
       ->init($_item, 'product_page_image_large')
       ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
       ->keepFrame(FALSE)->
       resize(270, 404)
       ->getUrl(); ?>
        <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>"
       <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php if($imgurl2){ echo $imgurl2;}else{echo $imageUrl;} ?>';" onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>';"/>
       <!--<div class="bl_black" ></div><!-->
       </span>
       </span>
       </a>
```

Comment: Use `->load($_item->getProductId());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the **developer mode** so every **warning** will be shown here.

so must define the variable first. If you are passing the value in condition.

```
$foo='';

if(//someconditon):

 $foo='//yourvalues';

endif;
```

Answer (score -2):

If this is cart item, then you can get product Id like this :

```
<?php foreach ($items as $_item): 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: omg, so horrible: using objectmanager like this is not clean, and the most horrible thing is to reload products... It's definetly not the proper way to do that. Except if you like having more than 500 SQL requests per page.

Comment: The code is execute one's per item, And I just provide another way to get product information.

Comment: And if there is 100 item ? I've seen Magento with more than 1000 request to print just 20 products. It's just horrible. But in a way, i'm glad people continue to spread those kind of tips: it's easier for me to handle a customer that is saying to me "my website is slow, i need you to make it faster" ;)

Comment: The questioner already used objectmanager in there code, So I give answer like this. If you have new question then you can Ask that question seprately.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question to point out the pb. When someone does something bad, you should tell him, not conforting him in his error. Or at least saying to him "hey, ok you can solve it like that, but that's not the proper way". That's why Magento 1 has a reputation of "a slow framework". Because developper never think about number of SQL request. nd making a _load_ in a foreach of a collection is often a bad idea :)  (and let's not discuss about the fact that we have to use repository now ;) )